# Logon problem can't fix it for months

Tags: 14.04

I can't use anything after I have logged onto my computer. So, in order to do that, I have to go to TTY and start Unity manually.How can I fix it so that I don't have to start Unity manually every time I start my PC

Comment: That's much better, thanks. Could you please describe what you see when you log in (maybe take a picture and link to it in your question)? Does it look like in the question [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](/q/17381/175814)? How exactly are you currently starting Unity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears – the symptoms are somewhat different but I believe the underlying cause can be fixed by one of the many answers.